# Simple regex tweaking

Tags: regex, fail2ban

In a `fail2ban` implementation, I have a `jail` that exists to curtail **getfloods**. I.e., too many GET responses within a time frame are banned.

`fail2ban` detects those via a rudimentary regex I have fed it. I.e.:

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.*"GET.*
```

That regex parses lines like the following in my nginx `access.log` files, and takes the necessary action.

```
39.54.230.53 - - [07/Mar/2016:11:59:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2;
```

Now I want to add a subtlety here. Instead of all GET lines, I only want to parse GET lines that pertain a specific url pattern starting with `/vote/`. See the following example:

```
31.13.113.92 - - [07/Mar/2016:15:36:48 +0000] "GET /vote/1564968/39947/5/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://example.com/?io
```

My question is simple. How do I tweak my regex? Will it simply be:

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.*"GET /vote/.*
```

Yes?

Comment: you can try it. it seems correct i am not familiar with fail2ban and what does <HOST> means but .*"GET /vote.... seams OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape the forward slashes.

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.*"GET \/vote\/.*
```